# Updating core data from modal

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios5, xcode4.2, nsmanagedobject, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I'm sure this must be a common pattern in iOS apps.  I have a list controller that displays a list of items.  I have a segue (using storyboards) to a modal for adding a new item, where I just collect the name.  Once dismissed, I will return to the list, update it to include the added item, and do a couple of other small things (lets say log something for simplicity). Crucially, I need to log something that is part of the list controller, not the modal controller.

At some point along the way I also need to insert the new item in to my managed object context.

I have tried two approaches:

1) pass the ManagedObjectContext into the modal's controller using PrepareForSegue.  Insert the new item into the context from the modal's controller. Works great to this point.  But now I want to refresh my view and write my log lines.  I can't put these in viewWillAppear because I don't want the lines to be logged at first load or any other time, only after returning from the modal.

2) make the list controller a delegate of the modal controller so that I can do all of my work in the list controller itself, and only call the list controller's code when the save button is used in the modal (averts the issue with running on every load).  But since Item is a managed object I can't create it without reference to the context, which the modal controller knows nothing about, so I can't insert the item in the modal.   I also can't pass it to the delegate and insert it in the List controller, since there is no way to create a managed object without the context.

What is the established standard for this kind of flow?  Maybe I should be using a combination of both - pass along the context to the modal controller so it can handle it's own insert, and then call the delegate code in the list controller just to handle the logging?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A combination of 1) and 2) is what I use. Create a new managed object in prepareForSegue and pass this to your modal view controller. Set your list controller as the delegate of the modal view controller, and update your logging in the delegate methods.

There is no need to have any core data heavy lifting in the modal, it doesn't need to know those things.

*(In fact, if you're only setting a name in the modal it doesn't even need to know about the object, you could just return a string, but if you do pass the object it gives you more flexibility if you decide to make it a bit more functional.)*

Comment: Ah, so you only create the managed object in the segue (using the context), and you pass this in rather than the context itself?  Presumably you then receive that object back in the delegate (with its attributes now set) and insert it the list controller? What happens if the user cancels the modal instead of confirming the addition?  What happens to the managed object you created in the list controller, that never got its attributes set and was never inserted?  Do I need another delegate attached to the cancel button to clean it up?

Comment: I am tempted by the simplicity of passing in the context to the modal, and creating the object in there, so that I can use the delegate only for the logging part.  But it seems a bit inelegant now that you mention your alternative.  Can you explain why it is better that the modal knows less about core data, and if it's significant enough to use so much delegation?  I wonder about a situation where I have no additional steps after insertion (no logging).  Passing in the context would mean that I don't need delegates at all, but by your reasoning should I still insert via delegation?

Comment: Think about encapsulation. Your list view controller already has to know about the MOC, so it makes sense that it is where all your addition and deletion takes place. Your modal's purpose is simply to configure the object you pass to it. Delegation is simple to implement and is a common and well-understood pattern in cocoa, so it makes sense to use it. If you had a cancel option in your modal, this could also be taken care of back in the delegate, which would simply delete the new object. You can do it an infinite number of ways, but you asked for an established standard...

Comment: Thank you.  Last question - would you stick to the same principle for a non-modal controller?  Including an n-deep navigation controller?  The principle you explain would dictate that all of my child view controllers should pass the object along and finally back to the delegate for insertion? I ask because I have seen many examples where the context is passed from view to view.  Is there something special about the modal (perhaps it's simplicity in my example)?  If the modal was much more functional would you send it the context?

Comment: In my example the object has already been inserted, so your last sentence isn't quite right. The answer is, it depends what you're doing, sorry! Note that any managed object carries with it a pointer to the managed object context so you don't need to pass that along separately.